# Через командную строку CURL работает, из PHP - нет

Tags: curl

Запрос из командной строки:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx-xxx-xxx' --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://site.com/address-classifier-ws/get_city_by_region_id_and_district_id_and_city_ua?region_id=9'
```

выдает города 9-го региона, и также остальных других (при смене region_id), как и должно быть.

Запрос из PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.com/address-classifier-ws/get_city_by_region_id_and_district_id_and_city_ua?region_id=9");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer xxx-xxx-xxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

выдает населенные пункты 9-го региона, но по остальным только ошибку:

```
{}ECOM_API_PRODN/A/ECOM_API_PROD.dbshttp://ws.wso2.org/dataserviceINCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR_getget_city_by_region_id_and_district_id_and_city_ua
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Нужно писать так:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . 'ХХХХ-хххх-хххх','Accept: application/json'));
```